# How to stream sensor data as an API response?

Tags: c#, api, stream, http-get

I have a device that reports back device state on HTTP GET methods.

I am developing an API where users can subscribe to a stream that will be provided by this API, which in turn will fetch data from the device with GET method and provide a stream to the users of API.

Users can then visualize this stream, store in DB, process on this data, or whatever they would like to do.

This is more or less like an RSS feed, where data is pushed to clients/subscribers. I don't know where to start. I tried looking up sensor data streaming as an API but nothing comes up with my desired functionality.

---

For simplifying the abovestated query, let's say I want to provide data stream, which could be used like this =>[https://plot.ly/~streaming-demos/6/streaming-mock-sensor-data/](https://plot.ly/%7Estreaming-demos/6/streaming-mock-sensor-data/), only instead of mock data, this data would be real. Behind the scenes, my service will be fetching data every second from the device and will push it X, where X might be an endpoint.

Comment: Have you checked the Azure IoT offerings? It's far easier and safer if the *device* posts messages to a server, eg the Event Hub or IoT Hub, or any other gateway you want to create. In general, you simply can't protect propertly an IoT device. The only safe option is if the *device* communicates with a well known server.

Comment: Having subscribers hit a device doesn't scale - devices can't handle more than a few clients (never mind security). Typical IoT architectures have devices calling a server using REST or, far better a queueing protocol like AMQP or MQTT, that can handle retries. The server can then notify the subscribers in any number of ways.

Comment: BTW the *entire* scenario upt to real-time line charts and maps is already available as an Azure offering (IoT Suite) and as individual services (Event Hub, Event Analytics, Power BI, Azure Functions). Keynote 2 of Build 2016 even shows a wearable "subscriber" - a polo shirt with leds that light up when temperature of a remote sensor falls below 20

Comment: these devices which I am using, does not call a server, instead we have to request and recieve response as a client .Let's a one of the service running in this device is Meter value, so we can read instantaneous meter values by sending HTTP Get one after another so we could be aware of real time data (some informatin is lost b/w 2 calls though). I can get this data by sending requesting from a pc which is directly connected to device, but that's not I want to do for full fledge system. I want to expose this data where user/client just be concerned with my API/method and subscribe that.

Comment: For Azure IoT or PowerBI ( I am not sure but i think they work on stream of data static or dynamic), and in my understanding, I need to build a stream for my device , so I can feed it to Azure or any other processing engine or just normal user.so the question is, how to stream? like a continues flow. endless data of device variable being fetched

Comment: That's the IoT gateway scenario - if the device can't talk to the Internet, you add a gateway device that can check the sensors, then send the data to the server. A Raspberry is more than enough to act as an IoT gateway, an Arduino, probably.

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/) for publishing events to Power BI in real time. [This tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/) shows how to create an Event Hub and post to it. Finally, the [IoT Hub(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/)  combines this and more features (eg simulated devices), specifically for IoT scenarios

Comment: Let me check this tutorial,but in the meantime, this unit is using a specific protocol (OCPP) for giving information regarding different devices aka sensor's data. 
Do you mean a raspberry pie for each unit as a IoT gateway?